# How to convert data rows to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a table `tblUser`, with columns

`userId,firstName,LastName,Mobile,.......,QuestionID`

I have another table it's name `tblResults`, with these columns

`questionID,Question,choiceID,choice,.........`

```
tblUser
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
userID -  FirstName- LstName -Mobile  ...     ...     ... -  QuestionID -  ChiceID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
001   -   xx     -     yy   -   03212          -                   01        01 
001   -   xx     -     yy   -   03212          -                   02        02 
002   -   xxx     -    yyy  -   03425         -                    01        02 
002   -   xxx     -    yyy  -   03425        -                     02        01  
003   -   xxxx    -    yyyy  -  03429         -                    03        02 
003   -   xxxx   -     yyyy  -  03429          -                   03        01 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

tblResults
---------------------------------------------------------------------
QuestionID   Question       ChoiceID       Chice    ....     ....            
---------------------------------------------------------------------
01        -    **Are you**   -  01   -   Male
01        -    **Areyou**    -  02    -  Female
02        -    **From**     -   01   -   xxxxx
02        -    **FROM**     -   02    -  yyyyy  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get result shown in following table

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UserID FirstName LastName  Mobile  **Areyou**   **From**
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001    -   xx     -  yy     -   03212  -  Male  -  yyyyy
002    -   xxx    -  yyy    -   03425   - Female - xxxxx
003    -   xxxx   -  yyyy   -   03429  -  Female -  xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the unique users with their respective choises for each question, and join in the tblResults table once for each question:

```
select
  u.userID, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.Mobile,
  q1.Choice as Areyou,
  q2.Choice as [From]
from (
  select userID, FirstName, LastName, Mobile,
  sum(case QuestionId when '01' then ChoiseId else 0 end) as ChoiseId1,
  sum(case QuestionId when '02' then ChoiseId else 0 end) as ChoiseId2
  from tblUser
) as u
inner join tblResults as q1 on q1.QuestionID = '01' and q1.ChoiseID = u.ChoiseId1
inner join tblResults as q2 on q2.QuestionID = '02' and q2.ChoiseID = u.ChoiseId2
```

Answer (score 0):

baically, we can create a table t (UserID, ChoiceID) for each question, then inner join all these tables. then we got (UserID, ChoiceID_for_Question_1, ChoiceID_for_Question_2, ...). add the userinfomation back, we got the desirable result.

```
select t1.UserID, t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.Mobile, t1.Choice, t2.Choice
from 
  (select u.UserID, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.Mobile, r.Choice
  from tblUser u, tblResults r 
  where u.questionID = '01' and u.QuestionID=r.QuestionID and u.ChoiceID = r.ChoiceID) t1
inner join 
  (select u.UserID UserID, r.Choice
  from tblUser u, tblResults r 
  where u.questionID = '02' and u.QuestionID=r.QuestionID and u.ChoiceID = r.ChoiceID) t2
/* 
inner join
  (...) t3
*/
on t1.UserID = t2.UserID /* and t2.UserID = t3.UserID */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to produce the results that you want.  There are two ways either a Static Pivot which you hard-code the columns or a Dynamic Pivot which gets the list of columns at run-time.

**Static Pivot:** (See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb9d4/1))

```
create table tblUser
(
    userid int,
    fname varchar(10),
    lname varchar(10),
    mobile int,
    questionid int,
    choiceid int
) 
insert into tblUser values (001, 'xx', 'yy', 03212, 01, 01)
insert into tblUser values (001, 'xx', 'yy', 03212, 02, 02)
insert into tblUser values (002, 'xxx', 'yyy', 03425, 01, 02)
insert into tblUser values (002, 'xxx', 'yyy', 03425, 02, 01)
insert into tblUser values (003, 'xxxx', 'yyyy', 03429, 03, 02)
insert into tblUser values (003, 'xxxx', 'yyyy', 03429, 03, 01)

create table tblResults
(
    questionid int,
    question varchar(10),
    choiceid int,
    choice varchar(10)
)
insert into tblresults values (01, 'Are you', 01, 'Male')
insert into tblresults values (01, 'Are you', 02, 'Female')
insert into tblresults values (02, 'From', 01, 'xxxxx')
insert into tblresults values (02, 'From', 02, 'yyyyy')

select *
from 
(
    select u.userid,
        u.fname,
        u.lname,
        u.mobile,
        r.question,
        r.choice
    from tbluser u
    left join tblresults r
        on u.questionid = r.questionid
        and u.choiceid = r.choiceid
) x
pivot
(
    min(choice)
    for question in([are you], [from])
) p
```

**Dynamic Pivot:** (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb9d4/2))

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.question) 
            FROM tblresults c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT userid, fname, lname, mobile, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select u.userid,
                    u.fname,
                    u.lname,
                    u.mobile,
                    r.question,
                    r.choice
                from tbluser u
                left join tblresults r
                    on u.questionid = r.questionid
                    and u.choiceid = r.choiceid
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(choice)
                for question in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Both will produce the same results.